# When is it safe to rebase a pushed feature branch

Tags: git, branch, rebase

I've read that I should not rebase a feature branch (to update it with changes from master to allow for a conflict-free merge later on) when it's already pushed to a shared repo unless I know the consequences.

So what are the consequences?

I'm the only developer on that feature branch and I don't care for myself if I rewrite history on it. But what are the implications on others?

I've listed some of the things I could think of. Please correct me and add more if you know.

1. Someone branched/rebased off of my branch: They get an unrequested rebase of their branch on their next pull
2. Someone merged my branch into theirs: They surprisingly get a changed merge commit and therefore possible conflicts on their next pull
3. Someone cherry-picked a commit: ???
4. There was an open Merge/Pull Request: Now points to rebased branch ???
5. Stuff linked to commits in Issues, MR/PR, Platform-Markdown: Point to updated files/commits?

Answer (score 1):

Consequences are for people who are basing their work on your branch prior to rebasing. Consider what happens if you did 3 revisions on your feature branch and developer B then started a branch from your branch and did 3 commits.... then you rebase... then eventually, your branch gets merged into, let's say, master. Nice...... that other developer finishes after the 3 revisions and asks to merge. What will history look like if that branch is merged straight? It will have duplicates for your 3 commits (the original revisions and the ones that came up after your rebase)... not the best thing to have, right? In that case the other developer had to rebase on top of your rebased branch or master after it was merged. The other tricky scenario is when you rebase a common branch and don't tell anybody. Suppose you correct the last 3 revisions of master and push force it to replace the common master.... if you have developers that are already working on the original master, when they tried to push changes into that branch, they wouldn't be allowed because branches have diverged and they haven't merged the new master (and they better don't because you would end up, again, with duplicate revisions.... they have to rebase as well).

Comment: Me personally? I think stuff should be rebased when it makes sense... making like a little harder for people working on the same project should not be a major problem since solving these kinds of issues only involves running a single rebase operation: `git rebase --onto new-rebased-branch old-rebased-branch my-branch`. So it's not like it's extremely hard to move stuff around after a branch has been rebased. The trick is to get the other developers to be aware of the history being rewritten so they can rebase their branch.